# casperjs capturing a "loading.gif" on ajax call

Tags: casperjs

I use casperjs 1.1 (phantom 1.9.8) for loggin a website.

After login, there's the spinning throbber and I have:

```
<div id=throbber style='display: block'></div>
<div id=main style='display: none'></div>
```

Some dynamic content is loaded in the main div, so after loading:

```
<div id=throbber style='display: none'></div>
<div id=main style='display: block'>some content</div>
```

I tried to get a screenshot of the loaded content, since I need to perform clicks and operations, but I always get the throbber picture. I tried to wait 30 seconds, to waitforselector, waitfor document.getElementById('throbber').style.display == 'none' but without luck...

I use the alwex/php-casperjs wrapper (with some handmade additions) so my last try looks like this:

```
$casper->click('button[type="submit"]');
$casper->waitFor("document.getElementById('throbber').style.display == 'none'"); //implicit 5000 timeout
$casper->capture($screenshot_large, time().'.png');
```

This particular try returns "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('throbber').style')" but I'm opened to any alternative.

Thank you for any suggestion or alternative.

Comment: Where does `waitFor()` come from? The mentioned framework doesn't have this.

Comment: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor

i added the support to the wrapper, just a couple lines of code. However alternatives are welcome, e.g. another unsuccessful try was waitForResource with the regex /main" .* block/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

casperjs demonstrated to be unreliable with such webpages.

A different solution based on Selenium perfectly worked.